# JMeter exception after test completes

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am observing the following issue while running a JMeter script from non GUI command through Jenkins pipeline.

---

```
The JVM should have exited but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], stackTrace:sun.misc.Unsafe#park
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport#park at line:175
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#await at line:2039
java.awt.EventQueue#getNextEvent at line:554
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpOneEventForFilters at line:187
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEventsForFilter at line:116
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEventsForHierarchy at line:105
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEvents at line:101
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEvents at line:93
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#run at line:82

Thread[AWT-Shutdown,5,system], stackTrace:java.lang.Object#wait
sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown#run at line:314
java.lang.Thread#run at line:748

Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main], stackTrace:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.awt` stands for [Abstract Window Toolkit](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-awt), you should not be seeing this form of messages given you run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode.

I can only think of a bug in JMeter like [64479](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64479) so if you have a [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) in your test plan - try removing it completely.

Other things to try:

- set `jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true` property in *user.properties* file
- make sure to follow recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article so your JMeter instance will be properly configured for high loads as JMeter's default settings are suitable for tests development and debugging but not sufficient for more or less immense load

Comment: In my case I resolved removing the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and I disabled my listeners on my Test Plan.